# SQL Server 2008 R2 database not accessible after instance started

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2

This is a bit of a problem! I had shut down an instance on SQL Server and today I started it up again.

However one of the databases (the main one that I work with) is not accessible.

When I attempt to expand the database in SSMS to view tables, I get the error:

> The database  is not accessible. (objectExplorer)

I found this article which looked like it may solve the issue (assuming that it is a permissions issue) but that did not work either: http://sqlserver-help.com/2012/02/08/help-i-lost-sa-password-and-no-one-has-system-administrator-sysadmin-permission-what-should-i-do/

In the SQL Server error logs I am seeing:

> FCB:Open failed: Could not open file E:\\.mdf for file number 1. OS error: 32 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

There is plenty disk space and so I am stuck with what the issue is.

I do have a recent backup so I'm not overly concerned about losing this database but still - I would like to be able to recover it if at all possible.,

Any help appreciated.

***UPDATE*** - I used ProcessExplorer which showed that sqlservr.exe is using the file EVEN AFTER STOPPING THE SERVICE!

When I attempt to detach the database I get an error about Primary files do not match or that log file is from different database. Confusing!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the issue was still - but it was resolved by rebuilding the log file.